# Curly brackets not working for form in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a problem with my form tags.

Try to use a code like `{{Form::label("label")}}` but have `&lt;label for=&quot;label&lt;/label&gt;`

Tried add these in app/start/global.php but problem still exist

```
Blade::setContentTags('{{', '}}');      // for variables and all things Blade    
Blade::setEscapedContentTags('{{{', '}}}');     // for escaped data
```

Any solutions ? Thanks in advice

UPD: my view file have a blade.php extension

UPD: 
Main view:

```
 {{Form::open(["url"=>"/admin/goods", "method" => "post", 'files'=>true])}}
            @include("admin.goods.form", array('tags' => "", 'props' => "")) 
 {{Form::close()}}
```

Form view:

```
<div class="row">
    {{Form::label("title")}}
    {{Form::text("title", null, ["class"=>"form-control"])}}    
</div> 

{{Form::submit("Send", ["class"=>"btn btn-primary", "id" => "submitForm"])}}
```

Comment: have you created blade file? i think it's inbuilt for blade no need to set tags

Comment: no need to set the tags and save your views as `.blade.php` it should work

Comment: @CodingInsane my view file have a blade.php extension

Comment: What if you use `{{{` `}}}`?

Comment: Can you show us your full view code please? (if it's much just the part around the problematic line)

Comment: @lukasgeiter, this happen only on provider server, but on local is all working properly - why, how do you think ? can php version affect to the blade templates? Also code {{ Form::open .... working properly, but not {{ Form::label.. It's confusing me...

Comment: You should have miss something, if Form::open works properly...
You should show us this part of your code because it's maybe a syntax error.

Comment: @KeizerBridge I have added part of code, labels, inputs and submit button not working properly

Comment: And what if you try to not include but have all your form on the same file ? Could be obvious but the only difference I see between Form::open and the rest is the use of @include blade function

Comment: thank you guyz, i think - its a php or smthg like that version problem, on another hosting provider everything working properly. thanks to all